# How to uncomment a commented line or block in JSCodeshift

Tags: jscodeshift

I have been trying to transform the commented lines in a script to uncomment them, But I couldn't find any.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you can easily google the solution. Such questions are not appropriate for SO. The community here expects people to ask pure technical questions and your question doesn't fit into that.

Comment: please upload a code sample and how you want it as end result.